# Multisite - restrict registrations to one site for all sites of the network

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I am trying to restrict site registrations and logins to one subdomain, And reroute login/registration requests from other sites to https://accounts.example.com and after sucessful login/registration send them back to the originally requested site.

I am working on a MultiSite install that is subdomain-based. A website that is doing something similar to what I am trying to achieve is the dev4press website. Check it out by going to https://plugins.dev4press.com/wp-admin where you will then be redirected to https://my.dev4press.com/wp-login.php this is exactly what I am trying to achieve.

The site at https://accounts.example.com should be exclusively for registrations/logins and profile management. I will have to integrate this with buddypress, woocommerce, bbpress, and wpdm (found here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/). These are all of the plugins I will be using that require authentication.

Thanks!